# Object representation of char * and void *

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

There is a claim in the Standard at `6.2.5(p28)`:

> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment 
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.

I don't really understand that. The object representation is defined as a content of `unsigned char[sizeof(the_type)]` obtained by `memcpy`.

So taking two arbitrary `char *` and `void *` like say:

```
int i = 10;
char * test1 = (char *) &i;

int j = 20;
void * test2 = &j;
printf("%d\n", test2 == test1); // prints 0
```

The code above prints `0` implying that the object representation of `test2` and `test1` is not the same, `6.2.6(p4)`

> Two values  (otherthan  `NaN`s)  with  the  same  object  representation
>   compare  equal.

***QUESTION:*** Does the clause assume that a pointer to void **converted from a pointer to a character type** shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type **from which it was converted**?

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with what kind of pointers they are. They point to different places so they are not equal. Even if you change the `void*` to also be `char*` the result will stay the same. Likewise if you change it so both point to the same place (for instance `i`) then the result is `1` no matter whether they're `char*` or `void*`.

Comment: The standard is talking about the object representation of **the pointer**, not the object representation of the **object pointed to**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's saying that if `int i; char *pc = (char *)&i; void *pv = &i;`, then `memcmp(&pc, &pv, sizeof pc) == 0`.

Comment: @melpomene So a pointer to `char *` converted to a pointer to `void *` (explicitly or implicitly) will have the same object representation. The Standard did not specify that explicitly, probably this is obvious since as @Blaze mentioned they are pointing to different objects and cannot compare equal.

Comment: I think here's a confusion on how terms are used in standard: *representation requirement of the type* and *object representation of the value*, which are slightly different things.

Comment: @user694733 Searching for the _representation requirement_ term in the Standard did not give any result. Can you give a reference to its definition?

Comment: There's probably no actual definition anywhere. I think it's more of what is implied by the difference in wording in chapters § 6.2.5 and 6.2.6.

Comment: @user694733 Probably that means that the size of `unsigned char[n]` should be the same... I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Representation" roughly means how things are stored in memory. The cited part 6.2.5 §28 dictates that certain pointer types must be stored in identical ways. The same paragraph makes a few more requirements to various other pointer types.

Apart from those pointer types listed, C gives some freedom to the implementation to store pointers in exotic and not necessarily compatible ways. But in practice this is misguided, since I don't think any real-world implementations ever did that. Instead systems with need of different pointer representations always seem to invent non-standard keywords for pointer qualifiers: `far` and `near`.

---

> The code above prints 0 implying that the object representation of test2 and test1 is not the same, 6.2.6(p4)

They point at different variables so of course it won't be the same - the pointers contain different values regardless of representation. To check if their *object representation* is the same, you must do this:

```
int i = 10;
char * test1 = (char *) &i;
void * test2 = &i;
printf("%d\n", test2 == test1); // prints 1
```

Or better: `printf("%d\n", memcmp(test1, test2, sizeof test1));`. Which prints 0 (equal).

---

> QUESTION: Does the clause assume that a pointer to void converted from a pointer to a character type shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type from which it was converted?

Yes because that is is required by 6.2.5 §28. We also have a requirement from the pointer conversions chapter 6.3.2.3 §7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

This too means that in practice all object pointers must have the same format internally, or otherwise the above wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @melpomene Yeah there's always some experimental, historic architectures. But beyond the area of computer archaeology, important systems were the mainstream MS DOS and countless microcontroller systems, where external addressing beyond 16 bits were needed. They all solved this by inventing `far` qualifiers, to avoid subtle bugs during pointer conversions. The C language simply failed to meet the real world requirements in sensible ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%d\n", test2 == test1);
```

The pointer test2 is different than test1 because you compare their values, that represent the locations of i and j.  I and J are different variables with different location for the object representing them.

So it is correct to be 0 the output.

In case that you do so:

```
int i = 10;
char * test1 = (char *) &i;
void * test2 = &i;
printf("%d\n", test2 == test1);
```

the output will be 1.

Comment: `char * test1 = &i;` I think this causes undefined behavior. Since the rules of assignment operator `6.5.16.1(p1)` _both operands  are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types_. So we need to cast explicitly as `char * test1 = (char *) &i;`.

Comment: @SomeName That would be "ill formed" rather than UB

Comment: @curiousguy In C++ maybe, but as far as I can tell the C Standard does not define the term "ill-formed program" or similar. At least searching for the word "ill" did not yield any usefull result.

Comment: @SomeName You are probably right here... I might have confused C++ and C terminology. My bad.